# CakePHP JSON Post validation not working?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm using CakePHP 2.1.1 and whilst my methods which use the form helper, for example my add method in my Users Controller validates correctly, I can't get my mobile_register method in the controller to validate, it saves even when data is missing.

This is my mobile_register method:

```
public function mobile_register() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $jsonData = file_get_contents("php://input");

        if(isset($jsonData) && !empty($jsonData)){
            $data = json_decode($jsonData,true);    
            $data = $this->User->configureUser($data);
            $this->User->create();

            if($this->User->save($data)){
                $jsonResponse = array('status' => 'OK', 'token' => $data['User']['token'], 'message' =>'SUCCESS');
            }else{
                $errors = $this->User->validationErrors;
                $this->log($errors,'errors');
                $jsonResponse = array('status' => 'ERROR','message' => $errors);
            }
        }
    }else{

        $jsonResponse = array('status' => 'ERROR','message' => 'API method expects POST data');
    }

    $this->set('response' , $jsonResponse);

}
```

I've been using curl to test my method and it always saves despite post the following data:

```
[User] => Array
    (
        [firstname] => Andy
        [token] => cc42030bbb49faf2cf0393418036e44f
        [role] => user
    )

 curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"User":{"firstname":"Andy"}}' url/users/mobile_register
```

My validation rules in my model are:

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'username-1' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Username is required',
        ),
        'username-2' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'message' => 'Usernames must only contain letters and numbers.',
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'password-1' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Password is required',
        ),
        'password-2' => array(
            'rule' =>  array('between', 5, 15),
            'message' => 'Passwords must be between 5 and 15 characters long.',
        ),

    ),
    'firstname' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Forename is required'
        ),
    ),
    'surname' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Surname is required',
        ),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email-1' => array(
            'rule'    => 'notempty',
            'message' => 'Email is required',
         ),
        'email-1' => array(
            'rule'    => 'email',
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email',
         )
    )   

);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better approach to this solution would be to make a good use of the "required" and "allowEmpty" validation options:

[CakePhp's data validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#required)

This is what solved my problem, I thought it was related with the way I was requesting the action, but instead it was that I wasn't even setting the fields I wanted to validate.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Basically I learnt that if you don't pass the fields then they will not be validated.